# MVC - Updating partial view moves div container

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

got an issue with updating partial views within my application.

Basically, after the login procedure the user will be redirected to a selection of archives to choose.
It should lead to a searchmask to enter some criterias to search for.

What I got is this:



**@_Layout.cshtml**

```html
<div id="_pview">
  <div class="container body-content">
    <div class="_pviewcontent">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <hr />
    <a class="copyright">@Html.ActionLink($"© Copyright 2006 - {@DateTime.Now.Year} MyCopyright", "Index", "About")</a>
  </footer>
  <div id="loading_image" class="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

**@ArchiveSelection/Index.cshtml**

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="_divpartialview">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_ArchiveSelection", Model);}
  </div>
</div>
```

**@ArchiveSelection/_ArchiveSelection.cshtml**

```html
<table class="table">
  @{
    if (Model != null) {
      foreach (var item in Model.FileCabinetList) {
        <tr>
          <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(item, "Index", "SearchMask", new {filecabinet = item}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "_divpartialview", LoadingElementId = "loading_image"})
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
  }
</table>
```

@RenderBody/RenderPartial() will show the list below the navigation bar.

[image]

After updating the div container with a partial view, it moves into the navigation bar.

**@SearchMask/_SearchMask.cshtml**

```html
<div style="height: 500px;">
  <div>
    <div style="height: 500px; width: 330px; float: left; background-color: aqua"></div>
    <div style="height: 500px; width: 330px; float: left; background-color: gray"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the container div (_divpartialview) moves right into the navigation bar after updating it.

Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it on my own.

I now feel pretty embarassed, because it was so simple. It was just a css template, that was colliding with bootstrap css.

Due to improper naming of some css classes this was the result.

Im kinda new to this, so don't laugh at me too hard :D